# Walk to run character transition

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm coding a 2D game, and I want the character to make a transition from the walking animation to the running one just by pressing the button a little harder, like modern games.

Is this possible?

Comment: My Answer is very simple, Yes this is Possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the controller being used. If it returns fractions between -1 and 1 when not pressed all the way down, then you would have what you need.

For example:

```
if (Input.GetAxis("WalkButton") > .5f) {

    // code goes here to make character run right

} else if (Input.GetAxis("WalkButton") > 0f) {

    // code goes here to make character walk right

}
```

Here is a button reference for the Xbox 360 controller: http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=Xbox360Controller

Comment: Thank you for your response .